# C# How to make overlapping areas drawn with graphics darker

Tags: c#

I am working on a small project that draws many filled circles on a form with the Graphics class and SolidBrushes. Is there a way to make areas darker when graphics are overlapping? I would like to have it so as more circles overlap, the overlapped areas get gradually darker in whatever color the circles are drawn in.

I have looked over the Graphics class documentation but I can't seem to find anything talking about this in it...but I might have missed something.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Use the Alpha component of the Color class.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Yes, a Winform. Sorry about that, I am relativity new to stackOverflow

Comment: As Lars wrote: Fill the Ellipses with a semitransparent color like `Color c1 = Color.FromARGB(64, Color.Blue)` or  `Color c2 = Color.FromARGB(64, 123,234,34)`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options, when a shape is transparent you will get the behavior you need.

a) Set opacity less than 1

```
<Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="#101010" Opacity="0.5"></Ellipse>
```

b) Use alpha colors to fill your shapes.

```
<Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="#50101010"></Ellipse>
```

Notice the Fill property of b) includes "alpha", that indicates opacity,

```
#50(alpha)10(Red)10(green)10(blue)
```

Comment: Is this done with the Brush class? I am finding no overload method with fillElipse that takes a variable for Opacity

Comment: This is done in ASP, right? So it is useless to the op.

Comment: I believe I have found the solution. This post helped.                                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue))

Comment: Well, somehow he doesn't know his ways around here as you can see from his comment above where he clearly stated that is is WinForms.